# Логические средства

Tags: недопустимая-метка, общие-вопросы

Что можно отнести к логическим средствам языка?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1) Логика и язык** [Реферат: Логика и язык | bestreferat.ru](http://www.bestreferat.ru/referat-153387.html)

Для выражения всех элементов рассуждения служат различные средства языка. **Понятия** выражаются посредством отдельных слов или словосочетаний, **суждения и умозаключения** — с помощью **простых или сложных предложений**.

**Имена предметов** обозначают единичные предметы, явления, события иди их множества. Объектом исследования в этом случае могут быть как материальные (самолет, молния, сосна), так и идеальные (воля, правоспособность, мечта) предметы.

**Имена признаков** — качеств, свойств или отношений — называются предикаторами. В предложении они обычно выполняют роль сказуемого (например, «быть синим», «бегать», «дарить», «любить» и т.д.).

**Основные логические связки**: — конъюнкция (союз «и»);— дизъюнкция (союз «или»); — импликация (союз «если..., то...»);

2) **Методы логической организации текста, типы связи между предложениями**

[Типы речи | studfiles.ru](http://www.studfiles.ru/preview/6152488/page:15/)

Синтаксические средства связи указывают:

а)  на последовательность развития мысли (вначале, прежде всего, затем...);

б)  на противоречивые отношения(однако, между тем, тем не менее);

в)  на причинно-следственные отношения(следовательно, поэтому, кроме того...);

г)  на переход от одной мысли к другой (прежде чем перейти к...,обратимся к,

рассмотрим, необходимо остановиться на);

д) на итог, вывод (итак, таким образом, значит, в заключение отметим, все

сказанное позволяет сделать вывод).

Answer (score 0):

```
     Что можно отнести к логическим средствам языка?
```

Сразу не очень поняла, о чём речь. Может быть, о средствах выразительности.

Средства выразительности условно делятся на логические и эмоциональные. Основными средствами логической выразительности являются: логическая пауза, логич. ударение, логич. мелодия и лог. перспектива.

Рассмотрим их.
Слова пишутся отдельно, а произносятся вместе. Однако не сплошным потоком. С помощью пауз мы разъединяем речевой поток на отдельные фразы и мелкие внутренне фразовые интонационно-смысловые единства - синтагмы, или так называемые языковые звенья.

Паузы, отделяющие фразу от фразы и синтагму от синтагмы, называются логическими паузами. Важно правильно определить место логических пауз в середине фразы. Неуместные паузы делают непонятной мысль, могут даже извратить её. Трудно воспринимается мысль при наличии лишних пауз. Слова, тесно связаны между собой грамматически и по содержанию, составляют одно языковое звено и произносятся  без пауз, вместе, как одно слово.

Продолжительность логических пауз определяется степенью связи между языковыми звеньями и между фразами, степенью завершённости мысли. Чем меньше связь, тем пауза длительнее. Паузы между фразами длиннее пауз в середине фразы. Разными они могут быть и между языковыми звеньями. Правильное определение соотношения продолжительности логических пауз помогает точнее выразить мысль и добиться естественной интонации диктора.

Важным средством логической выразительности является логическое ударение. В каждой фразе, как и в каждом языковом звене, есть важнейшее по смыслу слово. Его мы выделяем из других слов определёнными средствами: замедлением произнесения, усилением голоса, изменением высоты голоса (повышением или понижением), паузой перед словом (а иногда и после него). В основном  используем одновременно несколько способов. Такое выделение слов называется логическим ударением. В каждой языковом звене выделяется логическим ударением, как правило, одно слово. Итак, сколько во фразе языковых звеньев, столько и логических ударений, но одно из них всегда выступает основным. Называется оно фразовым.

Главное слово в предложении является смысловым центром, отражает отношение говорящего к предмету, к событию. Умение выделять ударные слова делает интонацию понятной. Такая речь легко воспринимается слушателями. Прежде всего нужно научиться снимать ударения с  остальных слов. Это облегчит фразу и выделит главное слово в предложении.

О речевых тактах можно прочитать здесь:

http://studopedia.su/15_55411_rechevie-takti-i-logicheskie-pauzi-ih-videlenie-v-zvuchashchey-rechi.html